# Matlab - read data from file while ignoring nan lines

Tags: c, matlab, nan, scanf

I have a file in which the data is stored in columns with a header above and marker points in between. It is a log of movement data recorded with a tracker and the markers are set for example each time someone hits "M" on the keyboard.
My question is, how do I read the data while checking each time if the line I'm trying to read is in the desired format? I know C pretty well, but have my problems with Matlab and the way the functions work there.
My approach so far was:

```
fId = fopen('Coordinates.txt', 'r');
i = 0;
A=zeros(10000, 17);
tline = fgetl(fId);
while ischar(tline)
    i = i+1;
    if isnan(tline)
    else
        A(i) = sscanf(tline, '%f %f %f %f %f %f %d %c %d %d %d %f %f %f %f %f %f', 17);
    end
% handX(i) = A(i,1);    
tline = fgetl(fId);    
end
fclose(fId);
```

If you see where I'm going with this?
(The beginning of) my file looks like this:

```
ID is 0001; Number of Trial is 012;
Time is Tue Sep 02 15:35:32 2014
V=Virtual

X [in]      Y [in]      Z [in]      ROLL [rad]  YAW [rad]   PITCH [rad] TIME [ms]   Avatar Style    Incongruence    VHI RLP VX [in]     VY [in]     VZ [in]     VYaw [rad]  VPitch [rad]    VRoll [rad]

2.548209    0.083796    -3.264887   -0.580893   -1.505823   0.147869    1935        h       0       0   0   -4.951791   -1.916204   -3.264887   -0.580893   -1.505823   0.147869
2.550583    0.083348    -3.269413   -0.579991   -1.506423   0.147635    2075        h       0       0   0   -4.949417   -1.916652   -3.269413   -0.579991   -1.506423   0.147635
```

So what I want to do is look at each line in the file, check if it starts with a number, skip the lines that are nan(), and also preferrably make a mark whereever I encounter a line that is nan(). Also, I want to save the values in separate vectors (like handX). So far, I only get the error that the number of elements in the line with the sscanf() call don't match.
Thanks!

Comment: As a general comment, it's best to explicitly provide the error and stack trace, not just a summary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think one of the main differences when using Matlab instead of C is that you normally don't need to do things in loops and avoiding loops in Matlab is generally faster.

You could read your data in easily with `textscan`:

```
fId = fopen('Coordinates.txt', 'r');
A = textscan(fId, '%f %f %f %f %f %f %d %c %d %d %d %f %f %f %f %f %f', 'HeaderLines', 6);
fclose(fId);
```

Reading your example file in with this yields `A` as a 1x17 cell array. Each cell contains a column of your data (a 2x1 matrix in this case).

`textscan` has quite a few options so I'm sure it can be tailored to your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

The error from your `sscanf` is just an [indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html) problem. As written, you're trying to write a 1x17 array into a 1x1 array.

The immediate fix is:

```
A(i,:) = sscanf(tline, '%f %f %f %f %f %f %d %c %d %d %d %f %f %f %f %f %f', 17);
```

One thing to note with `sccanf` is that it will convert characters to their numeric equivalents (each character will get its own column, important to note for string lengths greater than one), so your `'h'` strings from your example have been converted to `104`. If necessary you can convert it back to a string using [`char`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/char.html) or use a different function to parse the line. [`textscan`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html), for example, outputs a cell array so you can have mixed data types.

As a general aside, MATLAB defines `i` and `j` as the imaginary numbers, so utilizing them to increment may yield unintended consequences.

EDIT: You're also not accounting for your header lines. Incorporate some method to skip a certain number of lines so you're not trying to parse non-data into your data array.